# fixed column row height for all rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have used datatable js with fixed left column.
I couldn't able to reduce the row height.
How could I reduce or set row height?
I checked this link and other Stack Overflow answers.
http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/11828/how-do-i-set-the-row-height-in-datatables

For the first pages, they all are showing in the right height, but when i get to the end of the page, the last item covers all available space.

[image: the output of following the recommendations]

This is what I am getting.

Please assist me in this.

---

I use this to fix it,

```
.dataTable {
    display:block;
}
.dataTable tr td {
    min-width: 150px;
    height:20px;
}
```

If i can do it with the Datatable object it will be great.

Comment: Can you edit to clarify what you mean? Your question is a little confusing as is.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/yoyosh/DgsD6/

Comment: That's an example of what is happening to the rows.

Answer (score 0):

You did set the inline-style of the table to a fixed height.

```
<table id="a" style="height:400px;">
```

This is not a problem of datatables, this is normal behavior for tables in html. If you set an fixed height for the table-element the table will stretch all rendered rows and cells to fill that table-element.

You could remove that inline-style and set the row-height in the css:

```js
$(function(){$('#a').dataTable();});
```

```css
.dataTable th,
.dataTable tr {
  height: 2em;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.0/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.0/css/jquery.dataTables_themeroller.css">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.0/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
          
<table id="a">
  <thead>
    <tr><th>Id</th><th>Title</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>abcdef</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2</td><td>abcdef</td></tr>
    <tr><td>3</td><td>abcdef</td></tr>
    <tr><td>4</td><td>abcdef</td></tr>
    <tr><td>5</td><td>abcdef</td></tr>
    <tr><td>6</td><td>abcdef</td></tr>
    <tr><td>7</td><td>abcdef</td></tr>
    <tr><td>8</td><td>abcdef</td></tr>
    <tr><td>9</td><td>abcdef</td></tr>
    <tr><td>10</td><td>abcdef</td></tr>
    <tr><td>11</td><td>abcdef</td></tr>
    <tr><td>12</td><td>abcdef</td></tr>
    <tr><td>13</td><td>abcdef</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```